# how can i know which link fired the 'show' event in twitter modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using vanilla twitter bootstrap. I have a modal dialog that opens from multiple links, and want to change the content of the dialog according to which link opened it:

```
<a href="test/1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem">Edit 1</a>
<a href="test/2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem">Edit 2</a>
<a href="test/3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem">Edit 3</a>
```

And

```
<div id="editItem">
     <div class="modal-header">boo</div>
     <div class="modal-body">Loading...</div>
</div>
```

When they click, I want to figure out the firing href

```
$('#editSupportItem').on('show',function(e) {
   var link = ...magic...
   alert($(link).attr('href'));
});
```

Since the show event is on the modal dialog, not on the link, I can't seem to find a way to figure out the firing element. Obv. I could call modal directly from the link and not from data-attributes, but that wouldn't make me very happy!